# unity-count files in directory

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, filesystems

I have a problem with counting files in some folder on Android device in Unity after build and run .apk file. For testing in editor, I used this code:

`Levels = Directory.GetFiles(Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "Levels"), "level*.xml").Length;`

Is here any way to count or list files in some directory after build .apk file?

Comment: This might help you get an idea on how to solve it:

https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html

Comment: Considering the StreamingAssets gets turned into a jar file maybe it would be easier to use the Resources instead. You can use LoadAll and you done.